# GPS location display using my own map...not Google Maps

Tags: json, ios5, geolocation, geocoding, windows-mobile-gps

I'm trying to build an iphone app that will display my real-time location to my friends/family while I'm on my college campus. I don't want to use Google Maps or any other online map provider for the base map over which my location will be displayed. So, I've created a map of my college campus that is exactly proportional to my college campus in real-life. I even overlayed it in Google Maps to check it's accuracy.

Is it possible to georeference this map and then embed this map in my iphone app so that my location is displayed over it? That way I don't have to use Google Maps. I will need the user to be able to zoom-in on the map image to get a closer view of my location. My GPS location data will be delivered to the app via JSON data.